# Do native speakers also call Remote Cotroller just Remote always?

Tags: word-usage

I always thought calling TV Remote Controller just Remote is incorrect(I know in literal it's wrong ). But While watching Modern Family Series I found they mentioned Remote Controller as Remote. Is it so common saying just Remote?

Comment: *The remote* (as @Henry reminds us) is extremely common in most US households I've been in. I don't know about Britain, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, India, Nigeria, etc

Comment: I might say *the remote* rather than a plain *remote*, even if there is more than one

Comment: No, we don't. Sometimes we do; sometimes we don't

Please explain why you thought calling TV Remote Controller just Remote was incorrect and how literally, it's wrong…

Comment: What's interesting is when we drop 'control' or 'controller'.  When thinking about a TV, I would just say, 'remote'.  When thinking about a toy or model, I would say 'remote control'.  "Give your brother the remote control for the train."

Comment: Of related interest *[Thermostat vs. Remote Control](/questions/406214)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so common that it is also in dictionaries:

[Remote](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/remote):

> - A remote control device.

AHD

[Remote](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remote?q=Remote):

> - A remote control.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Also Oxford with plenty of examples https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remote  but I'm not that any of these entries tell a non-native speaker how frequently  the word is used.

Comment: @Clare- yes, I just mentioned a couple of dictionaries, but many other have the same entry. The fact that “remote” as a short for “remote control device” has entered most dictionaries is a clear indication that the term is commonly used.